# Append a number to every php instance

Tags: php

I have a form in my website where users can send messages to multiple recipients, they type in the recipient's numbers separated by commas, I recieve the numbers in my php script as a single post variable, but I need to add the recipient,s area code on front of every number, I have tried to explode the variable using the comma as a separator but I do not know what to do from there

```
$recipient=$_POST['recipient'];

$numbers=explode(',' $recipient);

for ($i = 0; $i <=sizeof($numbers); $i++) {

}
```

Comment: @OP You need to specify a bit more about your $numbers array or what your $_POST actually contains before you can expect more than this perfectly valid answer. Please also try a bit on your own before expecting a copy&paste answer! Answers where all valid based on your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how you're getting the area codes in the script, but to prepend the number with the area code, you can just use string concatenation, like so:

```
$areacode = 123; // this is received dynamically
$result = array(); // initialize empty array

for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($numbers); $i++) {
    $result[] = $areacode . '_' . $numbers[$i];
}
```

This can also be done using a `foreach`:

```
foreach (explode(',', $recipient) as $number) {
    $result[] = $areacode . '_' . $number;
}
```

Now, if you want to get this back as a comma-separated string, you can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode), like so:

```
$result_string = implode(',', $result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfectly!

Comment: @user2982450: Glad to have been of help! However, this question isn't likely to be useful to a future visitor. So, you may want to delete it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is something like:

```
$numbers_with_area_codes = Array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($numbers); $i++) {
  $numbers_with_area_codes[] = '+372'.$numbers[$i];
}
```